# Plotting temperature measuement

Tags: ilnumerics

I have temperature data that I would like to plot in i surface plot. I was thinking to put the data together in a matrix where the x-axis is time, the y-axis is a postion and the z-axis would be the data at that x-y-position (i.e. height, or in this case temperature). Is this possible using ilnumerics?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, sounds like a pretty common case. What have you done so far? Go here for a starting point: http://ilnumerics.net/surface-plots.html

Comment: Well, the thing is that I don't get how to use a mxn matrix with values to represent the "canvas" since all examples have a mathematical expression as an input.

Comment: If you read further down on that page there are some examples with numerical data. The last examples uses a 3 dimensional array to provide the data: MxNx3. You can ommit the 2nd and 3rd slices and only provide Z. Another source: http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/M_ILNumerics_Drawing_Plotting_ILSurface__ctor_1.htm - Does it help?